# Unable to call inherited method on Java object from coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, twitter4j

I'm using the twitter4j library and am having problems with one of the classes. In my code i get an instance of [RequestToken](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/auth/RequestToken.html#method_summary) returned from a function.  I can dump the variable to the screen and see that is in fact the correct class.  It has 2 public methods of it's own that i can use without issue, but it has 6 public methods inherited from [OAuthToken](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/auth/OAuthToken.html#method_summary) that i can't use. Coldfusion throws an error when i try to access any of them:

> ```
> Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types, or 
> the getTokenSecret method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot
> decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0 methods that matched the provided arguments. 
> If this is a Java object and you verified that the method exists, you may need to 
> use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity.
> ```

some of the relevant code:

```
<cfset twitterFactory = createObject("java", "twitter4j.TwitterFactory").init(config)>
<cfset twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance()>
<cfset RequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken()>
<cfset TokenSecret = RequestToken.getTokenSecret()>
```

Dumping the RequestToken i can see the java class names in the dump, and it shows the methods.

[image]

The two methods i need to use are getToken() and getTokenSecret().  Neither take any arguments, so there's nothing to javacast.

Using coldfusion8, and the latest twitter4j release 3.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks right to me: both the class and methods are `public`. It *might* be a bug. CF uses [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) to identify and invoke the methods. It usually gets it right, but not always. I have seen that happen once or twice in older versions. Usually with inherited methods.

If that is the problem, you could use reflection yourself as a work-around:

```
<cfscript>
    emptyArray = [];
    method = RequestToken.getClass().getMethod("getTokenSecret", emptyArray);
    result = method.invoke( RequestToken, emptyArray);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the work around!  Still confused/irritated that it didn't work in the first place, but at least i can move forward now.

Comment: Well from what I can see, the original code should have worked just fine. That is why I suspect a bug. You might want to check the bug database, just to see if anything similar was reported and/or fixed in later versions. Anyway, glad the work-around helped.